# Why the html custom form is not working django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a contact page with a simple form.

Here is views.py:

```
def contact_view(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ContactForm()
else:
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, settings.ADMIN_EMAILS)
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect('success')
return render(request, "base/contact.html", {'form': form})


def success_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

this is contact.html:

```
{% block content%}
<main class="page contact-page">
    <section class="portfolio-block contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>Contact me</h2>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="mb-3"><label class="form-label" for="name">Your Name</label><input class="form-control item" type="text" id="name"></div>
                <div class="mb-3"><label class="form-label" for="subject">Subject</label><input class="form-control item" type="text" id="subject"></div>
                <div class="mb-3"><label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label><input class="form-control item" type="email" id="email"></div>
                <div class="mb-3"><label class="form-label" for="message">Message</label><textarea class="form-control item" id="message"></textarea></div>
                <div class="mb-3"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg d-block w-100" type="submit" value="submit">Submit Form</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

When I use form.as_p it works very well but when I use this template it is not working
it only shows in the terminal that a post request was made.

Comment: It is because the html `form` is hardcoded and django doesn't work in that, it works in `Form` api,then only you can access values through `cleaned_data`, normally, you can get values of hardcoded html form from `request.POST.get("any_name")`, but it is better to use form api and that too in looping format, where we have more control over the all fields, specific field related errors and non field errors as well.

Comment: Thank you! Can you be more specific to this example maybe give some code based on my code? And also can you tell me how to keep this bootstrap styling? Sorry for my many questions.

Comment: Are you able to receive data submitted by user inside view for post method because action attribute is missing in your form tag.

Comment: I dont know how to see that.

Comment: @B.Anup if `action=''`, means blank or whether not given that means missing, django will take current page route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html looping syntax of form is following, where we have access to specific `field`, `field.label` ,`non_field_errors` as well as `particular field errors`.

In your case you can use in this way:

contact.html

```
{% block content%}
<main class="page contact-page">
    <section class="portfolio-block contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>Contact me</h2>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                    {% for error in form.non_field_errors  %}
                    <div>
                        {{error}}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                {% for field in form  %}
                <p>{{field.label_tag}} {{field}}</p>
                <br>
                    {% for error in field.errors  %}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

You can use it as above it will work perfectly with your existing views, as you said it is working with `form.as_p`.

If you give only `form.as_p`, it will render form fields in `<p>` tag of html, you can see through `Ctrl+U` of `view page source`,there we cannot have more control over form.

Your question -- `How can i use bootstrap's classes in django's form?`

Answer - You can set through [`widget`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#widget) in your form's fileds. for example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

In the above way, you can set it to every field.