# Django 3: ValidationError is not displayed

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-queryset

I recently started learning Django framework and had some problems with variable validation. When I try to output field.errors variable in html file there is no output, although when I pass error variable from create method, it outputs "errors" list (i.e. clean_number method is supposed to work) and when I fix them, list gets smaller (i.e. clean_number method does not work). Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

File create.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport>
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Adding a train to the list</title>
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    .sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 267px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 50px;
    }

    .container {
      max-width: 900px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<body class="bg-light">

<header class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-md-3 col-lg-2 me-0 px-3 fs-6" href="/">Home page</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute d-md-none collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebarMenu" aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100 rounded-0 border-0" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="nav-item text-nowrap">
      <a class="nav-link px-3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <main>
    <div class="row g-5">
      <div class="py-5 text-center">
        <h2>Add a train</h2>
          <p class="lead">On this page, you need to fill in all the fields and follow the instructions.</p>
            <form method="post">
            <div class="row g-3">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
              {{ field }}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  {{ field.errors }}
                  {% if !field.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <hr class="my-4">
              <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

File forms.py

```
from .models import Train
from django.forms import ModelForm, NumberInput
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class TrainForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Train
        fields = ["number", "amount_stops"]
        widgets = {
            "number": NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter the train number',
            }),
            "amount_stops": NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter the number of stops'
            })
        }

    def clean_number(self):
        number = self.cleaned_data['number']
        if number > 100:
            raise ValidationError('The number is over 100!')
        return number

    def clean_amount_stops(self):
        amount_stops = self.cleaned_data['amount_stops']
        if amount_stops > 100:
            raise ValidationError('The amount of stops is over 100!')
        return amount_stops
```

File views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import TrainForm


def create(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TrainForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            error = form.errors

    form = TrainForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }
    return render(request, 'main/create.html', context)
```

Changed the template, but still nothing has changed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}<p>
        {{ field.errors }}<p>
      {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

===========================

10/02/23: I tried to re-create the project without using the PyCharm IDE, just using Windows PowerShell, but nothing has changed, as it is not displayed and does not show(. My project creation:

1. Creating an AppDjango folder
2. In Terminal PowerShell:

```
-> cd D:\AppDjango\ - Navigate to Project
-> PS D:\AppDjango> python -m venv virenv
-> PS D:\AppDjango> virenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango> python -m pip install Django
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango> django-admin startproject AppDjango
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango> cd AppDjango 
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango\AppDjango> python manage.py runserver
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango\AppDjango> ^C (Ctrl + C) - Finish process
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango\AppDjango> python manage.py startapp MainApp
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango\AppDjango> python manage.py migrate
```

3. Next, I changed the configuration of the setting.py file:

```
import os                   <- Only added
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MainApp'               <- Only added
]
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),], <- Only changed
        ...
    },
]
```

4. I added the table to the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models


class Train(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    amount_stops = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)
```

5. I created the forms.py file and added the code:

```
from .models import Train
from django.forms import ModelForm, NumberInput
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class TrainForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Train
        fields = ["number", "amount_stops"]
        widgets = {
            "number": NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter the train number',
            }),
            "amount_stops": NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter the number of stops'
            })
        }

    def clean_number(self):
        number = self.cleaned_data['number']
        if number > 100:
            raise ValidationError('The number is over 100!')
        return number

    def clean_amount_stops(self):
        amount_stops = self.cleaned_data['amount_stops']
        if amount_stops > 100:
            raise ValidationError('The amount of stops is over 100!')
        return amount_stops
```

6. I added the code to the views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import TrainForm


def create(request):
    errors_Main = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TrainForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            errors_Main = form.errors
    form = TrainForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'errors_Main': errors_Main
    }
    return render(request, 'MainApp/create.html', context)
```

7. I created a new file D:\AppDjango\AppDjango\MainApp\urls.py and added the code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.create, name='create')
]
```

8. I also changed the file D:\AppDjango\AppDjango\AppDjango\urls.py (the one that originally generated Django):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('MainApp.urls'))
]
```

9. I created a template file .\MainApp\templates\MainApp\create.html and added code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}<p>
        {% for error in field.errors %} <- added
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

10. Recent changes to the PowerShell Terminal:

```
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango\AppDjango> python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'MainApp':
  MainApp\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Train
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango\AppDjango> python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: MainApp, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying MainApp.0001_initial... OK
-> (virenv) PS D:\AppDjango\AppDjango> python manage.py runserver
```

Result: Still does not display errors. Can you please tell me at what stage I screwed up?

Comment: It seems the issue is with template.

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey, I understood your thought process correctly, by template you mean the template of the html-file)?

Comment: Wait, I'd check and reply you later. Try to use looping syntax of template, see my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71896105/17562044) Answer, it may help you.

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey, Tried your version, still does not work(.  Maybe it will help if I send a description of the whole project? Or maybe some settings I did not set in the settings.py file? Development environment: PyCharm

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey, Maybe I don't fully understand the specifics of the framework? Please tell me how exactly (in what sequence) the .errors variable is initialized (or the whole process that validation goes through). Maybe this will somehow clarify the situation. Just basically, you may pass the dictionary with errors through method create (for example, I managed to output it through error.number), but it's kind of a crutch.) I would like to learn all the nuances correctly, rather than reinvent the wheel. Thanks in advance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Sunderam Dubey for helping. I found the answer to my question. The problem was in the create method, I rewrote it a little differently (code below) and I was able to display the error text:

```
def create(request):
    form = TrainForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TrainForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, "main/create.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the looping syntax of showing errors so instead of only `{{field.errors}}` use it as following:

```html
{% for error in field.errors %}
  {{ error }}
{% endfor %}
```